# How to click on elements inside a UL class in selenium using python? (There are options inside a drop down menu on a web page)

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[Drop down menu as seen on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhJ6b.png)

```html
<body class="controller-welcome action-index">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="select2-drop select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active" style="top: 51.2833px; left: 1151px; width: 190px;">
      <div class="select2-search">
        <ul class="select2-results">
          <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted">
            <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
              <div class="select2-result-label">
                <span class="select2-match"></span> samba
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
              <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
                <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
                  <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

`[Find this image for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywcDv.png)

I need to click on "samba" option from the drop down menu using python in selenium....Please help.   Also, please find the image attached for more clarification.

Comment: Show what you've tried already

Comment: I didn't tried as I am new to python programming language

Comment: You cannot just ask someone to write code for you. SO is not a code writing service. You should make some efforts to solve the issue and you failed- share the code you've tried and describe the issue.